# Different bibliographies entries with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have 2 different .bib files. In one file I have the publications I appear on and the other one is for the references I have used.
Right now, I include each file separately but I only get one bibliography section.

What I would like to have is two different entries: One, with the publications I appear on and  two, the references I have used to write my thesis.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `multibbl` is your best option here.

Reference: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multbib